# I need a tool for analysing my website SEO performance

Tags: google-search

I've recently looked for help on the market for SEO-help/providers but decided in the process that I should be able to do a lot of the work myself. Can anyone recommend a solid SEO-tool for analysing my site ([www.accobat.com](https://www.accobat.com/)) performance in terms of link rank and so on.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

I just put up a [free SEO analyzer](https://seoanalyzer.io/) you can check out, it will provide all kinds of useful metrics like site speed, a breakdown of improvements that can be made for on-page SEO, social signals, Alexa ranking, and more. I just released this application, let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

Google PageSpeed is really useful for technical issues that need optimisation:
https://developers.google.com/speed

A backlink checker is a great place to start try Semrush.